# Tabcontrol paints over main window childs

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, tabcontrol

Here is how the program looks as it starts :
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2dwgs4h.jpg  (can't upload images if I have less than 10 rep, sorry)

As soon as I hover with the cursor to change tab, every control which is not a child of the tabcontrol gets painted over in white as shown here :
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2yvuiwl.jpg

Here is how I created the TabControl in WM_CREATE:

```
RECT client_rect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &client_rect);

    TabControl = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_COMPOSITED, WC_TABCONTROL, L"", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        10, 10, client_rect.right - client_rect.left - 20, 
        client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top - 20, hwnd, (HMENU)110, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    TCITEM tab_info;
    memset(&tab_info, 0, sizeof(tab_info));
    tab_info.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    tab_info.pszText = L"Encoder";
    tab_info.cchTextMax = 5;
    SendMessage(TabControl, TCM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tab_info);
    tab_info.pszText = L"Decoder";
    SendMessage(TabControl, TCM_INSERTITEM, 1, (LPARAM)&tab_info);
    tab_info.pszText = L"Info Tab  ";
    SendMessage(TabControl, TCM_INSERTITEM, 2, (LPARAM)&tab_info);

    RECT tab_rectangle;
    GetClientRect(TabControl, &tab_rectangle);
    SendMessage(TabControl, TCM_ADJUSTRECT, FALSE, (LPARAM)&tab_rectangle);
    DefaultTabProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(TabControl, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)TabProc);
```

Every other control is a child of the main window, except for the two buttons on the left which are defined as childs of the TabControl it self.

I've subclassed the TC to be able to paint that 50x50 px bitmap in bottom left and I'm handling the WM_PAINT of the subclassed wndproc this way :

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    if (!BitmapCall)   //bool to decide whether I invalidated this rect to print the bitmap or not
        CallWindowProc(DefaultTabProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    if (EncodingTab)   //we are in the Encoding tab, so print the bitmap
    {
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        Graphics grap(hdc);
        grap.DrawImage(&(*bitmap), 20, 248);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        BitmapCall = false;
    }

    break;
}
```

Strangely, if I call   Graphics grap(GetDC(hwnd));    the problem does not arise, and I'd take this route if it wasn't for the great memory leak i'm facing over few dozens of seconds after the application starts.

I tried to handle Tabcontrol's WM_ERASEBKGND and just return TRUE without luck. I could then make every control child of the TC but apparently groupboxes and radio buttons doesn't like the idea and gets painted all in black leaving me with even more troubles.
Painting the bitmap from the main frame window looks impossible since it gets overpainted by again said TC,
I may finally try to handle the order in which everything gets painted but I have no clue on where to start/how to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` on the tab control.

Comment: Same output unfortunately

Comment: What happens when you substitute GetDC/ReleaseDC with BeginPaint/EndPaint?

Comment: Did it yesterday and it works, but can't draw outside TC's WM_PAINT. If I try to paint from anything else (eg. from a timer case) nothing shows up. This is really the weirdest win32 control